# Enumerable OrderBy used to order collection by multiple optional fields

Tags: c#, linq, enumerable

I have to order the child elements of a XML element. The child elements contain multiple elements that are not mandatory.

What I tried so far is:

```
var orderedElements = parent.Elements("ChildElement")
    .OrderBy(child => child.Element("Field1").Value.ToString())
    .ThenBy(child => child.Element("Field2").Value.ToString())
    .ToList();
```

The problem is that Field2 is not a mandatory element of `ChildElement` and I obviously get a null reference exception if `Field2` is not present in a `ChildElement`. Is it possible to modify the argument of `ThenBy()` to order the `ChildElements` after `Field2` only if `Field2` exists in the `ChildElements`?

Comment: Why don't you make an extension method called `ValueOrDefault(string elementName)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if the Field `element` exists:

```
var orderedElements = parent.Elements("ChildElement")
    .OrderBy(child => child.Element("Field1").Value)
    .ThenBy(child => child.Element("Field2") != null ? child.Element("Field2").Value : string.Empty)
    .ToList();
```

(BTW, you don't need to call `ToString()` on `Value`, since it's already a string)

Comment: This will still always order by `Field2`, it will just use an empty string for those children where the value is not available.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the ordering by `Field2` when **any** of the child elements has a missing `Field2` child, it's not possible to modify the argument of the `ThenBy` method, but you can do this:

```
var orderedElements = parent
    .Elements("ChildElement")
    .All(child2 => child2.Element("Field2") != null) ?
        parent.Elements("ChildElement")
            .OrderBy(child => child.Element("Field1").Value)
            .ThenBy(child => child.Element("Field2").Value)
            .ToList() :
        parent.Elements("ChildElement")
            .OrderBy(child => child.Element("Field1").Value)
            .ToList();
```

If you just want to ignore the missing `Field2` children and still apply the ordering based on the `ChildElements` elements that have a `Field2`, you may use @Thomas Levesques's approach, with the mention that the elements with a missing `Field2` will appear first in the ordered list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need to apply the ordering by Field2 even if it's missing from some of the child elements.